# Draw Rounded Intersect Lines

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics, uibezierpath, rounded-corners

I have to create a tab with buttons and some custom border (Images below). Problem is I have to add `cornerRadius` for each intersect but I'm not sure how to do it properly.

I have this code to draw tabs with border:

```
private func drawBorder(selectedTab: UIButton) {
        // The Tab frame (below one)
        guard let tabContainerFrame = vTabContainer?.frame else { return }

        let borderColor = selectedTab.titleColor(for: .selected)

        let tabFrame = selectedTab.convert(selectedTab.bounds, to: self)
        let topMargin: CGFloat = 5
        let tabOrigin = CGPoint(x: tabFrame.origin.x, y: tabFrame.origin.y - topMargin)

        // Make paths to draw
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: tabOrigin) // Origin (top left)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tabFrame.maxX, y: tabOrigin.y)) // -> right
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tabFrame.maxX, y: tabFrame.maxY)) // -> down

        if tabFrame.maxX != tabContainerFrame.maxX {
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tabContainerFrame.maxX, y: tabContainerFrame.origin.y)) // -> right
        }

        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tabContainerFrame.maxX, y: tabContainerFrame.maxY)) // -> Down
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tabContainerFrame.origin.x, y: tabContainerFrame.maxY)) // -> left
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tabContainerFrame.origin.x, y: tabContainerFrame.origin.y)) // -> up

        if tabOrigin.x != tabContainerFrame.origin.x {
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tabOrigin.x, y: tabContainerFrame.origin.y)) // -> right
        }

        // Close the path. This will create the last line automatically.
        path.close()

        // Draw
        let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        borderLayer.path = path.cgPath
        borderLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        borderLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel
        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor?.cgColor
        borderLayer.cornerRadius = 10
        borderLayer.lineWidth = 2
        layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)

        self.borderLayer = borderLayer
    }
```

This is the result:

[image: Tab1]
[image: Tab2]

As you can see, even though I add `cornerRadius = 10`, it just doesn't work. `borderLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound` and `borderLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel` doesn't help also.

Bonus:

I'd like to have a way to implement dynamic `@IBInspectable var lineCornerRadius: CGFloat = 10`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `UIBezierPath` to draw a shape, setting cornerRadius will have no effect on that path.

Instead, you want to use `path.addCurve(to: ...)` to make your rounded corners.

For example:

[image]

- the green dotted line is tabFrame
- `pt1` is tabFrame's "left" and "top + 10" (your radius)
- `pt2` is tabFrame's "left + 10" and "top"
- `pt3` is the first curve's second "control point" - the top-left corner of tabFrame
- `pt4` is tabFrame's "right - 10" and "top"
- `pt5` is tabFrame's "right" and "top + 10"
- `pt6` is the second curve's second "control point" - the top-right corner of tabFrame

So

```
path.addCurve(to: pt2, controlPoint1: pt1, controlPoint2: pt3)
```

adds a curve **to** `pt2` ... **from** `pt1` ... with curve control point of `pt3`

then:

```
path.addLine(to: pt4)
```

adds a line **from** the current point (`pt2`) **to** `pt4`

then:

```
path.addCurve(to: pt5, controlPoint1: pt4, controlPoint2: pt6)
```

adds a curve **to** `pt5` ... **from** `pt4` ... with curve control point of `pt6`

The rest of your shape is normal line segments.